# Deep link from web app to "post status update" in native Facebook mobile app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

Is this possible?

This opens the Twitter native app and populates the message. Is there something similar for Facebook for a status update?

twitter://post?message=Hello

I've seen this: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

And it's great... but I can't find an example of posting an update.

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to pre-fill the text in any case; it must be typed in by the user.

Comment: Thanks. Foo-ie. That sucks for me and my app.